# HTML5 Canvas Drawing History

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing, undo

I'm curious to know how applications such as Adobe Photoshop implement their drawing history with the ability to go back or undo strokes on rasterized graphics without having to redraw each stroke from the beginning...

I'm wanting to implement a similar history function on an HTML5 drawing application I'm working on but duplicating the canvas after every stoke seems like it'd use too much memory to be a practical approach, especially on larger canvas'...

Any suggestions on how this might be implemented in a practical and efficient manner?

Comment: Don't try to save the entire canvas after each stroke. Save each drawing command into an array.  Then you can undo by popping the last element(s) off the end of the array, clearing the canvas and redrawing all the remaining elements (== re-executing all the remaining drawing commands).

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm trying to avoid because it takes too long to redraw... I'm wondering how Photoshop and similar applications handle it, they don't redraw everything from the beginning...

Comment: Canvas is fast enough to redraw most drawings from scratch.  Although I don't have the Photoshop source, I suspect that PS actually does redraw from scratch using commands rather than saving entire raster breakpoints. I say this because the PS history lists all the commands. And PS Actions certainly work by playing commands.

Comment: Well I've already been using the method you suggested, and it can take a long time to redraw if there are a lot of strokes or if I'm trying to blur and do other related actions... Therefore, I'm looking for an alternate approach. :) Thanks though...

Comment: @markE suggests the right direction. Re-drawing shouldn't last more than, say, 10ms, so you should benchmark your code. Notice that you can use both a canvas to store the image at a given point, and on the other hand a stack of command from this point to now. From time to time you 'cut' the stack and update the stored image to the new beginning of the command stack. This way you'll have undos and quick redraw -but limited in time-. But again, first thing i would check is why drawing takes so much time. After all, some intense video games runs ok (on desktop) with the Context2d...

Comment: (another thing : by using a Proxy on the context2D, you can build the command stack very easily (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)).

Comment: Well, this isn't my site, but I'm basically trying to do something like: http://www.iscribble.net/gallery/drawing743636-Frozen.html (click the image to see a replay) If it goes much faster than that, especially in Firefox, it begins to lag on the redraw... I want to be able to make more of time slider, like a video, on my site. But that would mean being able to have near-instant redraws...

Answer (score 1):

I may have a solution.....

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvasId").getContext("2d");
var DrawnSaves = new Array();
var Undo = new Array();
var FigureNumber = 0;
var deletingTimer;
function drawLine(startX, startY, destX, destY) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
    ctx.lineTo(destX, destY);
    ctx.stroke();
    var Para = new Array();
    Para["type"] = "line";
    Para["fromX"] = startX;
    Para["fromY"] = startY;
    Para["toX"] = destX;
    Para["toY"] = destY;
    DrawnSaves.push(Para);
    FigureNumber++;
}
function undo() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    Undo[FigureNumber] = DrawnSaves[FigureNumber];
    DrawnSaves[FigureNumber] = "deleted";
    FigureNumber--;
    drawEverything();
    startTimeoutOfDeleting();
}
function undoTheUndo() {
    FigureNumber++;
    DrawnSaves[FigureNumber] = Undo[FigureNumber];
    drawEverything();
    clearTimeout(deletingTimer);
}
function drawEverything() {
    for (i = 0; i < DrawnSaves.length; i++) {
       if (DrawnSaves[i].type == "line") {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(DrawnSaves[i].fromX, DrawnSaves[i].fromY);
          ctx.lineTo(DrawnSaves[i].toX, DrawnSaves[i].toY);
          ctx.stroke();
       }
    }
}
function startTimeoutOfDeleting() {
   setTimeout(function() {Undo[FigureNumber] = "deleted";}, 5000);
}
```

This is really simple, first I draw a line when the function is called and save all his parameters in an array. Then , in the undo function I just start a timer do delete the figure drawn i 2000 miliseconds, clears the whole canvas and makes it can't be redrawn. in the undoTheUndo function, it stops the timer to delete the figure and makes that the figure can be redrawn. In the drawEverything function, it draws everything in the array based on it's type ("line here"). That's it... :-)
Here is an example working : [This, after 2sec UNDOs then after 1sec UNDOTHEUNDO](http://jsfiddle.net/9hca9Lx2/3)