# HTML5-Canvas: how to remove the just painted object?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a problem with HTML 5 Canvas. I want to do kind of "versioning". So I want to be able to draw several lines with canvas. But then with a button I want to be able to delete as many drawn lines as possible. Is there a possiblity to do that?
Thanks vor helping

Comment: Are you talkling about a drawing application or what's the purpose of those lines? Can you share your code?

Comment: If it's only several, you could consider transparent overlayed canvases, but otherwise, drawing on canvas is a permanent marker--you can draw over it or erase portions, but there's no undo or layers. More details about your actual use case would be helpful--if it's only "several", multiple canvases is probably workable, but if "several" means 500, you might need a different approach, probably involving redrawing the whole canvas from history line by line.

Comment: I yet do not have any code. What I was thinking of was to undo objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Remove previous drawn object in canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16969787/html5-remove-previous-drawn-object-in-canvas)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365436/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25819684/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297389/

Answer (score 0):

Keep an array of lines (maybe start/end points) and when you are drawing, loop through the array and draw all the lines.